# Как получить массив

Tags: php

есть массив

```
array(7){   
    [0]=>   array(7) {
        ["id"]=>     string(2) "13"     
        ["id_user"]=>     string(1) "2"     
        ["id_serial"]=>     string(1) "6"     
        ["date"]=>     string(10) "2016-06-26"     
        ["active"]=>     string(1) "1"     
        ["total_count"]=>     string(1) "4"     
        }   
    [1]=>   array(7) {
        ["id"]=>     string(2) "17"     
        ["id_user"]=>     string(1) "2"     
        ["id_serial"]=>     string(1) "5"     
        ["date"]=>     string(10) "2016-06-26"     
        ["active"]=>     string(1) "1"     
        ["total_count"]=>     string(1) "2"     

    } 
}
```

он приходит в пременую $tday к переменой $top оношщение не имеет вот код

```
$count=0;
foreach($top as $post){
     тут код 
    foreach ($tday[$count] as $today) {
        var_dump($today)."<br/>";

    }
    и дальше код
$count=$count+1;
}
```

в чем суть мне надо получить массив который соответствует номеру итерацци  foreach($top as $post) цикла и дальше с ним работать но я получаю так

```
    string(2) "13" string(1) "2" string(1) "6" string(10) "2016-06-26" string(1) "1" string(1) "4"
    string(2) "13" string(1) "2" string(1) "6" string(10) "2016-06-26"    string(1) "1"   string(1) "4"
```

я бы все же хотел получить при первой итерации

```
[0]=>   array(7) {
         ["id"]=>     string(2) "13"     
         ["id_user"]=>     string(1) "2"     
         ["id_serial"]=>     string(1) "6"     
         ["date"]=>     string(10) "2016-06-26"     
         ["active"]=>     string(1) "1"     
         ["total_count"]=>     string(1) "4"     
            }
```

и при  второй

```
[0]=>   array(7) {
        ["id"]=>     string(2) "17"     
        ["id_user"]=>     string(1) "2"     
        ["id_serial"]=>     string(1) "5"     
        ["date"]=>     string(10) "2016-06-26"     
        ["active"]=>     string(1) "1"     
        ["total_count"]=>     string(1) "2"     

    }
```

что бы я мог с ними работать к примеру что бы внести условие

```
$count=0;
foreach($top as $post){
    foreach ($tday[$count] as $today) {
        echo $today['id']."<br/>";
        $count=$count+1;}
}
```

и получить

```
13
17
```

учитывая что массивов будет десять

Comment: Непонятно. Хотите получить массив с одинаковыми ключами?

Comment: Или он Print_r хоча....

Comment: @ может я не правильно выразился мне надо достать два масивами но так что бы они остались массивами

Comment: @Sergalas чисто отобразить? ну так `echo '<pre>'; print_r($today); echo '</pre>';` .....вместо принт можно и вардамп

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я внес изменения посмотрите может сейчас хоть чуть объеснил что надо.

Comment: А ну так делайте цикл `for` от нуля до count($today) и выводите `$today[$i]['id']` ...... типа `for ($i=0; $i<count($today);++$i) { echo $today[$i]['id'].'<br/>'; }`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский не все так просто там массив в массиве и вначале запускается один цикл . потом в тот цикл  выводится ещё один массив из десяти массивов и надо обработать тот массив номер которого совпадает с номером итерации первого массива. Если хотите внесу изменения так как примерно это выглядит.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я внес изменения

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Цикл **foreach** и так служит для перебора массивов. **$count** не нужен. 
Вы уже получаете при каждой итерации следующий массив, с которым можно работать.

```
$arr = array(   
    [0] => array(
        ["id"]          => "13",    
        ["id_user"]     => "2",    
        ["id_serial"]   => "6",    
        ["date"]        => "2016-06-26",    
        ["active"]      => "1",     
        ["total_count"] => "4"     
    ),
    [1] => array(
        ["id"]          => "17",    
        ["id_user"]     => "2",    
        ["id_serial"]   => "5",    
        ["date"]        => "2016-06-26",     
        ["active"]      => "1",     
        ["total_count"] => "2"     
    )
);

foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
    echo $value['id'].' '.$value['date'];
}
```

Comment: я чуть изменил что бы вы поняли почему я в вел счечик

Answer (score 1):

вот так получается 
$count=0;

```
foreach($top as $post){
     тут код 

     $today = $tday[$count];
    echo $today['id']."<br/>";

    и дальше код
$count=$count+1;
}
```